# Displaying html codes in php

Tags: php, html

This is my code:

```
<?php 
   $baseurl = '<base_url>';
?>
<font class="font_style"><?php echo $baseurl;?></font>
```

When iam trying to display the variable $baseurl it takes as  as a html tags and nothing will bedisplayed

But i want to display as:

```
<font class="font_style"><base_url></font>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Your code should output exactly what you want.

Comment: Also, please don't use `<font>`. It's deprecated, and bad practice. For what you're doing, try `<span>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($baseurl);?>
```

Check [htmlspecialchars<sup>doc</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and  [htmlentities<sup>doc</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 3):

```
<font class="font_style"><?php echo htmlentities($baseurl);?></font>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the html entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of the special characters `<` and `>`.

Same goes for some other characters, most prominently `&amp;` instead ot `&`. Here's a reference for you:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Comment: Also, what @Alice and @xdazz said - there are PHP functions for that, `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`.